# Instant set root a page, instead pop it after confirm

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have an Ionic 2 application and I need to show a confirmation alert when user wants to go back.

I already have it working:

```
ionViewCanLeave() {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create(
            {
                //title: 'Are you sure?',
                message: this.CONFIRM_EXIT_MSG,
                buttons: [{
                text: 'Si',
                handler: () => {
                    this.stopAfterLeave();
                    resolve();
                },
            },
            {
                text: 'No',
                handler: () => {
                    reject();
                }
            }],
        });

        confirm.present();

        this.customizeConfirmPrompt();
    });
}

ionViewWillLeave(): void {

    this.goToHomePage();
}

public goToHomePage(): void {

    this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage,
    {

    },
    {
        animate: true,
        direction: 'back'
    });
}
```

But the problem is: When user confirm to go back, this page pop() and 1 second later it go to the home page.

It's like:  HomePage --> A Page --> Other Page --> The actual page

I'm in "The actual page", when press native back button, or navbar back button, I need to set root the "HomePage", instead go to the "Other Page" and then go to "HomePage"

Comment: How about in `goToHomePage` before `setRoot` add this line `this.navCtrl.pop(TheActualPage)`

Answer (score 0):

To go to Root page you can use this

```
public popToRoot(){
 this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
}


<ion-buttons>
  <button ion-button (click)="popToRoot()" icon-only>
    <ion-icon ios="ios-arrow-back" md="md-arrow-back"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-buttons>
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes I know, but I don't know how to do this when user accept the confirm message... when control goes by the path of resolve ();

Comment: Because when the user press native back button, or navbar back, it try to pop the actual page automatically.. I need to override this behavior.